# How to avoid selected list item moving to top of the list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrolltop

I have RecyclerView which contains 50 items in it. I will navigate one by one using Remote control unit up and down buttons. To select any item (e.g 25th) I'm using `recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position)` method. After this selection the item automatically moves to top position of the list. I don't want my selected item to go top of the position. I wanted to be the same selected position. How do I achieve this?

Thanks,
K. Rajesh

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Are all of your items the same size, or variable?

Comment: @Submersed Yeah i have only one text field in my list item.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an up and down control, that are complete separate from the actual `ViewHolder`s of the `RecyclerView`, you could just use `RecyclerView.scrollBy(x, y)`.

Assuming all of your items are the same size, you don't even have to take the "selected item" index into account, since there's no possibility of variability in item height.  Just use the View at the first position and scroll by either a positive or negative height on each up or down button click.

A partial example in Kotlin would look something like this if you're using a `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`:

```
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.up).setOnClickListener {
        val temp = recyclerView.layoutManager.findViewByPosition((recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())
        temp?.let {
            recyclerView?.scrollBy(0, -it.height)
        }
    }

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.down).setOnClickListener {
        val temp = recyclerView.layoutManager.findViewByPosition((recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())
        temp?.let {
            recyclerView?.scrollBy(0, it.height)
        }
    }
```

Also, note that if you added in `ItemDecoration`s to your `RecyclerView`, you would need to take those extra spacings into account when doing the scroll by.

Comment: this is not working. If i use smoothScrollToPosition(position) it scrolls and moving 20th item to the first visible item.  But i dont want this moving. How to resolve this.

Comment: My answer does not include a solution that uses scroll to a position, it just uses scroll by...